# Starting a .exe file but won't work?

Tags: c#

I wanted to start a .exe file in a different folder but I wanted other people to also use it and I've been trying many things but it just keeps opening the file that the program that I'm creating is in. (I'm new to c#).

My ex of ^: \Desktop\VSCheatDetector\CheatDetector.exe(the program) and another regular file named viper_screenshare_tool and it has CheatDetector.exe (which I want to open when I click a certain button)

Code:

```
    private void cheat_smasher_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        Process.Start(dir, "vipers_screenshare_tool\\CheatDetector.exe");        
    }
```

Comment: what do you think: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` does???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; - I'd suggest using App.config or something like that instead.